# How to display a video on a page?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I need to use Platform View to display the native video player AVPlayer for ios. I have my sample code, but it doesn't output anything to the page. When I go to the VideoPlayerPlatformView page I get a black screen on the simulator. How can I display the video on the page?
My Swift:

```js
import UIKit
    import Flutter
    import AVKit
    import AVFoundation
    public class VideoView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
        let frame: CGRect
        var _view: UIView
        init(
             frame: CGRect,
             viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
             arguments args: Any?,
             binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
        ) {
                _view = UIView()
                self.frame = frame
                super.init()
                createNativeView(view: _view)

            }
        public func view() -> UIView {
               return _view
            }
            
        func createNativeView(view _view: UIView){
              preparePlayer()
          }
          
        private func preparePlayer() {
            let url = URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8")
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer.frame = self.view().bounds
            self.view().layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

My Flutter:

```js
class VideoPlayerPlatformView extends StatelessWidget {
  static const StandardMessageCodec _decoder = StandardMessageCodec();
  const VideoPlayerPlatformView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return const UiKitView(
        viewType: "VideoPlatformView",
        creationParamsCodec: _decoder,
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the frame to the `_view` in the `VideoView`, because I didn't see frame updating

Comment: I have updated the code. Did you mean it?

Comment: yes, that is what I was thinking.

Comment: I still have a black screen. Could this be because I don't have viewDidLoad()? How can I add it?

Comment: What is `self.view()` in `VideoView`? is that `self.view()` have frame for it?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your UiKitView inside a container,

```
Container(width: 400,height: 300,
        child: UiKitView(
  viewType: viewType,
  layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  creationParams: creationParams,
  creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
);)
```

and inside the native view, provide a fixed frame for the video player

```
playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100.0)
```